# Can't display products custom fields under title in Woo commerce Cart section

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

I have created some custom fields for my product in wocommerce. I want to add those custom fields under title in cart page. This is the code I am using but with no result.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_isbn_in_cart', 20, 3);

function add_isbn_in_cart( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

    $custom_isbn = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_isbn_field', true );  
    return $title . $custom_isbn;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_ID()` would be returning the ID of the cart page, whereas you need the ID of the product post. You need to get the ID from the `$values` array.

`$custom_isbn = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_isbn_field', true );`